# Asp net core 2.2 http client System.Net.Sockets.SocketException

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

**TL;DR**:

To send requests we were using the bad approach before:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
```

Recently we migrated to the recommended HttpClientFactory. Since the migration we are getting System.Net.Sockets.SocketException when sending requests between our services.

**In more detail**:

As said before we were doing the bad new HttpClient() for each request we sent with a using block.
According to a few blogposts it was a bad thing to do, we experienced it's bad side effects and went with the recommended approach to use IHttpClientFactory and let dotnet do it's thing:

- https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/introduction-to-httpclientfactory-aspnetcore
- https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-2.2

So we replaced our ugly using blocks with the recommended way of sending requests:

```
public class RestClient
{
    private IHttpClientFactory clientFactory_;
    public RestClient(IHttpClientFactory clientFactory)
    {
        clientFactory_ = clientFactory;
    }

    public HttpResponseMessage SendRequest(HttpMethod httpMethod, string requestUri, List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> headerContent, HttpContent content)
    {
        using (var requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(httpMethod, requestUri))
        {
            // business logic
            var response = clientFactory_.CreateClient("businessRestClient").SendAsync(requestMessage).Result;
            // process and return
        }
    }
}
```

We create and addour named HttpClients with their handlers with these extension methods:

```
    public static IServiceCollection AddRestClient(this IServiceCollection collectionBuilder)
    {
        collectionBuilder.AddHttpMessageHandlers();
        collectionBuilder
            .AddHttpClient("businessRestClient")
            .AddHttpMessageHandler<BusinessRequestHandler>()
            .AddHttpMessageHandler<HttpLoggingHandler>();

        collectionBuilder.AddScoped<RestClient>();
        return collectionBuilder;
    }

    private static IServiceCollection AddHttpMessageHandlers(this IServiceCollection collectionBuilder)
    {
        collectionBuilder.TryAddTransient<HttpLoggingHandler>();
        collectionBuilder.TryAddTransient<BusinessRequestHandler>();
        return collectionBuilder;
    }
```

Within our servies the RestClient is passed to constructors by the DI and execute our requests calling that. (We are aware of using .Result for an async method is not a good idea)

Okay, so according to every blogpost, MS post we read on the topic suggest everything should be good right? So we deployed our services and within mintes we started getting **this exception**:
*System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted*

So we checked azure portal and metrics for our App Service Plan and saw that at the time of deploys a bunch of tcp connections were closed and after the deploy they went up again and were not in closing, close wait state at all. Basically our services behaved just like before except they are barely usable now due to the constant stream of exceptions we are getting.

Some advice would be nice or some information if anybody had this issue and how they solved it,

thanks!

--- EDIT ---

Our request handler
The requesthandler looks like this:

```
    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // Cookies
        if (!request.Headers.Contains("HEADERNAME"))
        {
            var cookies = new List<System.Net.Http.Headers.CookieHeaderValue>();
            var sessionInfoCookieStore = await idInfoAccessor_.GetSessionInfoCookieStore();
            if (signedCookieOptionsAccessor_.Options != null && sessionInfoCookieStore != null)
            {
                string cookieValue = sessionInfoCookieStore.GetCookieString();
                cookies.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.CookieHeaderValue(signedCookieOptionsAccessor_.Options.CookieName, cookieValue));
            }

            // Add headers
            request.Headers.Add("HEADERNAME", HEADERVALUE);
            request.Headers.Add(HeaderNames.Cookie, cookies.Select(cookieHeader => cookieHeader.ToString()));
        }

        // Response
        var response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
        return response;
    }
```

The other request handler just logs a few lines with ILogger before and after the request

Comment: You have deadlocks waiting to happen in that code with that .Result. I would say that needs to be fixed first using proper async code. Could you perhaps also post the code from your handlers? could be them causing the issue.

Comment: Can you please go more into detail about what you ment with deadlocks? @ThomasSchmidt

Comment: Also added the request handler to the original post

Comment: The TLDR doesn't explain anything. HttpClient isnt' new and works. So does HttpClientFactory. You get a SocketException but *what* does it say? Post the full exception text - that includes the call stack and any inner exceptions. You can get that easily with `Exception.ToString()`. Don't just post the call stack, post the actual output of `Exception.ToString()`

Comment: As for the code itself, it has some issues and *doesn't* follow the patterns in the linked articles. First of all, don't use `.Result`. HttpClient doesn't have any blocking methods for a reason.  `SendRequest` should become an asynchronous method. Using async all the way to the top (the actions) allows far greater scalability which translates to serving far more requests per server, or rather, requiring far smaller/fewer servers to serve the same traffic

Comment: Second, `RestClient` is a typed client which means it should accept an `HttpClient` in the constructor, not the `IHttpClientFactory`. The articles show that it should be registered and configured with `AddHttpClient`. Controllers that depend on `RestClient` in their constructors will receive a fully configured instance through the HttpClientFactory

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thanks for the replies, I'll look into the things you mentioned and start fixing them!

Comment: Finally, all the articles explain that the code should create and reuse *one* instance of HttpClient. `RestClient` does the *exact opposite* - it creates a *new* instance for each RestClient instance without releasing (disposing) it. This will quickly exhaust the socket connection pool. It's little different from using `var client=new HttpClient();` in each request, exactly what the articles say not to do

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thanks for all the feedback, I indeed misunderstood the usage of HttpClient after some refactoring based on your input it works just fine. We also removed all the .wait() and .Result calls from our code and started using await. The code became a lot more clean also we noticed some performance improvements as well.